# How to hide a Dialog without hide the Main Form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, modal-dialog

In the main form "frmMain.vb" I have a button that when it is clicked runs the following code:

```
    Dim myform as New frmMyDialog
    myform.ShowDialog()
```

On the "frmMyDialog.vb" form the user can start a public function of the main form and I need to hide the dialog until the function ends, so I wrote this code:

```
Private Sub btnStartProcess_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStartProcess.Click

    'hide the dialog
    Me.Hide()

    'start the sub of the main form
    frmMain.TestSub()

    'close the dialog
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

However, when the dialog becomes hidden, the main form is minimized. How can I hide the dialog without also hiding the main form?

(The "formBorderStyle" property of "frmMyDialog.vb" is "FixedDialog", I don't know if it can help.)

Comment: Why do you need to hide the dialog? If you reach your objective the user will see a frmMain completely locked caused by ShowDialog(). I think that is not a good interface design.

Comment: if I hide the dialog, the main form is not completely locked. It can be closed.

Comment: I've set this situation up and don't get the same problem. My main form remains visible.